# Чтение Excel документа C# (Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "double" в "string")

Tags: c#, excel

Есть класс который тянет инфу из Excel документа, он работает до тех пор пока ему не попадётся числовое значение в таблице, с текстом проблем нет.
Создал 2 документа. В одном ряд чисел от 1 до 4 прописью (один, два, ...), а в другом - в десятичном представлении (1, 2, ...).

В первом случае все выводиться на консоль, а во втором выходит исключение `Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "double" в "string"`.
Подскажите где я накосячил?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace OpenReadExcelFilesDemo
{
    class Excel
    {
        string path;
        _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();

        Workbook wb;
        Worksheet ws;

        public Excel(string path, int Sheet)
        {
            this.path = path;
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            ws = wb.Worksheets[Sheet];
        }

        public string ReadCell(int i, int j)
        {
            i++;
            j++;
            if (ws.Cells[i, j].Value != null)
            {
                return ws.Cells[i, j].Value;
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            Excel excel = new Excel(@"H:\TEST.xlsx", 1);
            Console.Write("{0}\n", excel.ReadCell(0, 0));

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена.

```
Convert.ToString(ws.Cells[i, j].Value);
```

Comment: ws.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString();